# How do I append the data or json received from this request to an empty array?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using a custom codable class Events. How do i append the resulting json from a request to an empty array so as to populate the table ?

```
var events = [Events]()

let URL_GET_DATA = "http://192.168.100.4/PrototypeWebService/api/getevents.php"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Alamofire.request(URL_GET_DATA).responseJSON{ response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                print(json)
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()


                    self.EventTable.reloadData()

                } catch {
        }

        }

 }
}
```

Comment: Add the JSON that you're parsing.

Answer (score 0):

pass your array data from your model to the array you created, after doing this

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let genaricModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(EventModel.self, from: JSON.data(using: .utf8)!)
```